# Chaining Mark Event on Calendar

Tags: android

This [image]

Im really wondering how to make those Chaining Mark in Calendar. Most Calendar are just plain mark the event with different color. I want to achieve this kind of Chaining. Any idea how can I do that? Been looking for some tutorial couldn't find any. Partly because the keyword I am using is different. I dont even know the proper term for this. SO I just call it chaining. Anyone?

Comment: What application is this?

Comment: @azizbekian its from habithub app. Any idea how the developers did that?

Comment: It seems to be a custom view. Look tutorials how to make calendar views. Maybe [this](https://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-create-android-custom-calendar-view-with-events/) or [this](https://www.toptal.com/android/android-customization-how-to-build-a-ui-component-that-does-what-you-want).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This guys](https://github.com/sickmartian/CalendarView) have a library that maybe you can customize, they have a feature similar to what u want.

[image: Preview]

Or [this one](https://github.com/MOLO17/CustomizableCalendar)

[Preview Here](https://github.com/MOLO17/CustomizableCalendar/blob/master/static/CalendarDemo.gif)

Or maybe [this one](https://github.com/AppliKeySolutions/CosmoCalendar)

[Preview Here](https://github.com/ApplikeySolutions/CosmoCalendar/blob/master/pictures/Calendar-range-years_2.jpg)